# MOSS 2007: How to programmatically store web part properties for a user?

Tags: 2007, storage

I have a web part which shows data in one of 3 different formats. The format is selected by clicking one of 3 buttons in the web part. This works fine.

A request has come through to store the last selected state so that the user does not always have to click their favourite view.

It seemed logical to define a Property and define **Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User)** but this does not seem to work for most users as they only have Read rights for the page.

What is the best way forward here? Is Sharepoint the right place to store such info or should I be using my own storage?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also store the last selected state in a cookie. This works for all users including anonymous ones. It is easy to implement and it does not take up any storage on the server.

Comment: Adding a link or an example might help clarify your answer.